# What does status "aborted" mean in firefox?

Tags: firefox, httprequest, httpresponse

[image]

**What does it (aborted) mean in firefox browser?
And why does it happen? 
Is it cause by which reason ? is the server refused these request or these request is missing to reach the server , and so on ? **

Comment: You should be able to take alook at the request and response data. It should give you more information than`aborted`. Also what view is this, it doesnt kook like the standard `F12` network tab.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot It looks like Firebug. Anyhow, I'm pretty sure "Aborted" means the request was cancelled before it was completed.

Comment: Ok ,if it is Firebug, he should take a look at the `F12` network tab, there he will see the request and response headerse with ease.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot `F12` will open Firebug if it is installed, unless they change the Firebug hotkey. That is of course, unless they are using Firebug 3+/Firebug Next.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot  , thanks . I do what you mean, I forgot to see the response's detail information. I will update my firebug.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara thanks a lot.

Comment: https://getfirebug.com/downloads/ , the current stable version is 2.0.7.